# Callback function being read as an Object?

Tags: javascript, callback, protractor

I am trying to do some Protractor tests and decided to create a general function to test multiple test cases

at the top of my `todo-spec.js` I have the following function:

```js
function bomImport(filePath, numLines, alternates, rejected)
{
  it('should import a BOM with ' + String(numLines) + ' lines.', function()
  {
    var customerSelection = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('select[formcontrolname="customer"]')).findElement(by.css('option[value="AMX|NOVI|MI"]'));
    var projectName = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[formcontrolname="project"'));
    var quoteType = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('select[formcontrolname="type')).findElement(by.css('option[value="bid"'));
    var quantities = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[formcontrolname="quantitie0"'))
    var fileName = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[type="file"'));
    var importedLines = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('imported'));

    customerSelection.click();
    projectName.sendKeys("import Test");
    quoteType.click();
    quantities.sendKeys('100');
    fileName.sendKeys(filePath);
    browser.waitForAngular();

    expect(importedLines.getText()).toEqual(numLines)
  })

  it('should reject ' + String(rejected) + ' lines.', function()
  {
    var rejectedLines = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('rejected'));

    expect(rejectedLines.getText()).toEqual(rejected);
  })

  it('should have ' + String(alternates) + ' alternate components', function() 
  {
    var numAlternates = browser.driver.findElement(by.id('alternates'));

    expect(numAlternates.getText()).toEqual(alternates)
  })

}
```

and I am implementing the function like this also in `todo-spec.js`

```js
describe('BOM Import Test 1', bomImport('T1 2599B BOM Reformat 4.xlsx', '1050', '1049','0'));
```

When protractor gets to this point it errors out with the message

```
describe expects a function argument; received [object Undefined]
```

but as far as I understand it, I am passing in a function? So I am a little confused by the error

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
describe('BOM Import Test 1', bomImport('T1 2599B BOM Reformat 4.xlsx', '1050', '1049','0'));
```

You executes the function and passes the return which is undefined.

You can send it to describe as a parameter. then it will be executed inside the code of describe function. but it will not pass your parameters for it.

If you want to pass the function this will be the code

```
describe('BOM Import Test 1', bomImport);
```

But it will not receive 'T1 2599B BOM Reformat 4.xlsx', '1050', '1049','0' as parameters

Comment: So at what point then could I use those parameters because the goal is not to have to write the same￼ bunch of code over and over again

Comment: try 
`describe('BOM Import Test 1', () => {bomImport('T1 2599B BOM Reformat 4.xlsx', '1050', '1049','0')});`